# Internal server error 500

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't view my admin area and blog

```
[19-Mar-2020 15:54:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/medicine/public_html/wp-includes/version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/medicine/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 24
[19-Mar-2020 15:54:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/medicine/public_html/wp-includes/version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/medicine/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 24
[19-Mar-2020 15:54:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/medicine/public_html/wp-includes/version.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/medicine/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to do an

```
ls
```

on /opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear

I doubt if the files are there
A reinstall would probably fix the issue

Comment: Sir now my host install new WordPress.